# Can I have multiple local repository for maven?

Tags: maven

In maven settings, there is an entity which refers the local repository:

```
<localRepository>~/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

When I add another one, like this:

```
<localRepository>~/another/place</localRepository>
```

it raises `Duplicated tag` error.

Can I have multiple local repository or maybe add another direcotry to the local repository?

**EDIT**
This idea seems a possible answer, too:

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/path/to/repo
```

Comment: do you want to resolve artifacts from multiple repositories or split the local repositories you download artifacts into between maven versions or projects?

Comment: I want tor resolve artifacts from multiple repositories.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can have and you can do it in your `POM.xml` itself. Below is an example.

```
<project>
...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>firstrepo</id>
      <name>repo</name>
      <url>http://myrepo.my</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>secondrepo</id>
      <name>repo2</name>
      <url>http://myrepo.yours</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
...
</project>
```

Second Method by creating `profile` in your `settings.xml`

For **multiple local repositories** you can have multiple `settings.xml` file.
In the command line specify alternate path using
`mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/path/to/repo` For more information you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2019915/1309392). Hope it helps.